# Getting correlations only for selected variables using a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, indexing, data.table, correlation

I have a dataset as follows:

```
set.seed(1)
TDT <- data.table(Group = c(rep("A",40),rep("B",60)),
                      Id = c(rep(1,20),rep(2,20),rep(3,20),rep(4,20),rep(5,20)),
                      Time = rep(seq(as.Date("2010-01-03"), length=20, by="1 month") - 1,5),
                      norm = round(runif(100)/10,2),
                      y = sample(100,100),
                      x2 = round(rnorm(100,0.75,0.3),2),
                      x3 = round(rnorm(100,0.75,0.3),2),
                      x4 = round(rnorm(100,0.75,0.3),2),
                      x5 = round(rnorm(100,0.75,0.3),2))
```

I would like to create a new dataset with by me selected correlations of `TDT`. 
To get the correlation of the dependent variable and selected independent variables (`xcor`) with all other independent variables I tried:

```
# getting the numerical variables
numcols <- names(Filter(is.numeric,TDT))

# getting the correlation of y with all x
TDT.y.cor<- TDT[, cor(.SD, y),.SDcols = numcols, by = Time]

# getting the correlation of selected x with all other x
xcor <- c("x2","x3")
TDT.x.cor <- TDT[, cor(.SD, xcor),.SDcols = numcols, by = Time]
```

But the last one gives the error:

```
Error in cor(.SD, xcor) : 
  'y' must be numeric
```

So now I want to make a for loop instead. Something like:

```
xcor <- list ("x2","x3")
for (i in xcor) {
TDT.xcor[[i]].cor <- TDT[, cor(.SD, xcor[[i]]),.SDcols = numcols, by = Time]
}
```

Which is not the correct syntax. Any suggestions?

Comment: **Self Promotion** If you don't mind, I wrote up `get_var_corr` that can handle such a case available at [manymodelr(develop)](https://github.com/Nelson-Gon/manymodelr/tree/develop/R)

Comment: What is the dependent variable? You can for instance do: `manymodelr::get_var_corr(Filter(is.numeric,TDT),
                         comparison_var = "y",get_all = TRUE)` or specify with `get_all=FALSE` and supply a vector of your variables. `manymodelr::get_var_corr(Filter(is.numeric,TDT),
+                          comparison_var = "y",get_all = FALSE,other_vars = c("x2","x3"))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Disclaimer** This answer uses the developer version of [manymodelr](https://github.com/Nelson-Gon/manymodelr/tree/develop) that I wrote.

To get the correlation between all xs and y, we could use:

```
manymodelr::get_var_corr(Filter(is.numeric,TDT),
                         comparison_var = "y",get_all = TRUE)
```

This yields:

```
   Comparison_Var Other_Var      p_value Correlation    lower_ci  upper_ci
1              y        Id 0.7660224000  0.03013023 -0.16727786 0.2252155
2              y      norm 0.5323952847  0.06316715 -0.13492501 0.2564040
3              y        x2 0.7032924284 -0.03855859 -0.23321046 0.1590642
4              y        x3 0.4898005278  0.06985644 -0.12832239 0.2626704
5              y        x4 0.2702013263  0.11131634 -0.08700408 0.3011500
6              y        x5 0.0009658689  0.32510267  0.13746236 0.4902174
```

To do just for select variables(ie x and a few xs):

```
manymodelr::get_var_corr(Filter(is.numeric,TDT),
                          comparison_var = "x2",get_all = FALSE,other_vars = c("x4","x5"))
  Comparison_Var Other_Var   p.value Correlation    lower_ci  upper_ci
1             x2        x4 0.5593246  -0.0590762 -0.25256366 0.1389543
2             x2        x5 0.1787881   0.1355323 -0.06255102 0.3233427
```

You can save the result and get other stats eg the summary output.

**EDIT**:
To use specific variables, one could use the variant `get_var_corr_` that supports combinations as follows(The first column can be discarded):

```
get_var_corr_(filter_df) %>% 
   filter(Comparison_Var %in% c("x2","y") & Other_Var %in% c("x4","x3"))
   .id Comparison_Var Other_Var   p.value Correlation    lower_ci  upper_ci
1 Var2              y        x3 0.4898005  0.06985644 -0.12832239 0.2626704
2 Var2             x2        x3 0.6239815 -0.04961512 -0.24365870 0.1482477
3 Var2              y        x4 0.2702013  0.11131634 -0.08700408 0.3011500
4 Var2             x2        x4 0.5593246 -0.05907620 -0.25256366 0.1389543
```

Comment: Hey NelsonGon. I tried your code. Very nice! The only thing is that for my question I would like to do it for multiple comparison variables.

Comment: You can get those variables and map them to the `other_vars` argument. @Tom For instance, which variables for this particular data? There is the variant `get_var_corr_` that simply does combinations. `get_var_corr_(Filter(is.numeric,TDT))` .

Comment: I am not sure if I follow haha.. So what would the syntax be if I would like to compare `x2` and `x3` (as comparison var) with `x4` and `x5` (as other vars) ?

Comment: Try this: `manymodelr::get_var_corr(filter_df,
                         comparison_var = c("x2","y"),get_all = T)` although it does return a warning. I would go with `get_var_corr_(Filter(is.numeric,TDT))` and keep only combinations I need. Note the underscore. And filter as so: `get_var_corr_(filter_df) %>% 
  filter(Comparison_Var %in% c("x2","y"))` and the `filter` for the other_vars too.

Comment: My apologies. I tried that and it actually works (I thought I got an error, but those are indeed just warning messages). I prefer `get_var_corr(filter_df, comparison_var = c("x2","y"),get_all = T)` because my actual dataset is ridiculously big. What does the warning `1: In data.frame(Comparison_Var = comparison_var, Other_Var = x, p.value = res1$p.value,  :
  row names were found from a short variable and have been discarded` mean exactly? Once again, brilliant solution, thank you so much!

Comment: @Tom please check the edit. I would go with the solution in the edit as it's more flexible. As for the warning, it's R's way of dealing with duplicated `row.names`.

Comment: If you are still working on improving your library and want to make it more idiot (me) proof: I noticed that the entire operation fails if there is one column which only has NA's (I created one on accident). It took me a while to figure why it was not working.

Comment: @Tom, thanks for the feedback. Please let me know by raising an issue with the example [here](https://github.com/Nelson-Gon/manymodelr/issues). I will be happy to take a look.

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```
numcols <- names(Filter(is.numeric,TDT))
xcor <- c("x2", "x3")
TDT[, data.table(var=xcor, t(cor(.SD[, mget(numcols)], .SD[, mget(xcor)]))), by=Time]
```

output:

```
          Time var          Id        norm           y           x2           x3          x4           x5
 1: 2010-01-02  x2 -0.04843595  0.26582680 -0.66584960  1.000000000 -0.061024243 -0.69292534  0.194408505
 2: 2010-01-02  x3  0.39631671 -0.26906428 -0.58788152 -0.061024243  1.000000000 -0.54623949 -0.787149320
 3: 2010-02-02  x2  0.08165416  0.26828706 -0.10444724  1.000000000 -0.120104310  0.08966978 -0.687626977
 4: 2010-02-02  x3 -0.77420649  0.06331042 -0.62424401 -0.120104310  1.000000000 -0.92782037  0.520999829
 5: 2010-03-02  x2  0.53328988 -0.76471756  0.09583857  1.000000000 -0.255684070 -0.57216005  0.583055924
 6: 2010-03-02  x3 -0.03208419 -0.40639968 -0.93857812 -0.255684070  1.000000000  0.21778224 -0.690868245
 7: 2010-04-02  x2 -0.40027209  0.12681443 -0.04596013  1.000000000  0.817854430 -0.31396988  0.188876433
 8: 2010-04-02  x3  0.10876596 -0.23779053 -0.06729634  0.817854430  1.000000000 -0.12087380  0.162171044
 9: 2010-05-02  x2  0.47014025  0.39570025 -0.10324192  1.000000000 -0.353894786  0.62548822  0.861633507
10: 2010-05-02  x3  0.60481815  0.64806521  0.64669485 -0.353894786  1.000000000 -0.76302787 -0.032024563
11: 2010-06-02  x2 -0.29866753 -0.03715892  0.02678853  1.000000000  0.722765758  0.85305747  0.215180135
12: 2010-06-02  x3 -0.71939635  0.18631833  0.20915545  0.722765758  1.000000000  0.90883928  0.338190647
13: 2010-07-02  x2  0.19959128 -0.06868888 -0.38153376  1.000000000 -0.205761177 -0.13574954  0.106505491
14: 2010-07-02  x3 -0.82150037  0.53153382 -0.56734304 -0.205761177  1.000000000  0.23196740  0.254086025
15: 2010-08-02  x2 -0.84788586  0.06205274  0.04195958  1.000000000  0.290333143 -0.17452641 -0.387409233
16: 2010-08-02  x3  0.17476552 -0.39239246  0.07572605  0.290333143  1.000000000  0.12847199 -0.417170776
17: 2010-09-02  x2 -0.28424279 -0.35470966  0.36559401  1.000000000 -0.004094751 -0.60601077  0.429553721
18: 2010-09-02  x3  0.17492786  0.12234080 -0.68318074 -0.004094751  1.000000000 -0.71591012 -0.867131063
19: 2010-10-02  x2 -0.59009254 -0.30596460 -0.20279720  1.000000000 -0.418992781 -0.33474959  0.331402645
20: 2010-10-02  x3 -0.03950447 -0.57650894  0.47707048 -0.418992781  1.000000000  0.61174441 -0.635031910
21: 2010-11-02  x2  0.44280504  0.15356142 -0.41594497  1.000000000  0.130022288 -0.57901168  0.056711167
22: 2010-11-02  x3  0.10088665 -0.19195643  0.47057457  0.130022288  1.000000000  0.64359334  0.947634532
23: 2010-12-02  x2  0.93528272 -0.08754048  0.47678028  1.000000000  0.640307246  0.76212510  0.129150650
24: 2010-12-02  x3  0.33922514 -0.12389088  0.74214451  0.640307246  1.000000000  0.96349801 -0.102219394
25: 2011-01-02  x2 -0.82681063  0.28813098  0.03680233  1.000000000 -0.670768877 -0.81895896  0.665160850
26: 2011-01-02  x3  0.37233376  0.44439836 -0.21498926 -0.670768877  1.000000000  0.96249265 -0.171852151
27: 2011-02-02  x2  0.78406829  0.87265449  0.44109646  1.000000000 -0.170824594 -0.31318417  0.419451424
28: 2011-02-02  x3  0.18246574 -0.53572698  0.34238233 -0.170824594  1.000000000  0.21508906  0.456834070
29: 2011-03-02  x2 -0.56012875  0.61468934  0.37723894  1.000000000 -0.628199774 -0.66904419 -0.051205610
30: 2011-03-02  x3  0.38559989  0.19407633  0.47882281 -0.628199774  1.000000000  0.26507006  0.457066183
31: 2011-04-02  x2  0.06213453  0.27072902 -0.56611872  1.000000000  0.756519929 -0.01807478 -0.240390425
32: 2011-04-02  x3 -0.34954142 -0.40531930 -0.44445227  0.756519929  1.000000000  0.44535133  0.364169201
33: 2011-05-02  x2  0.91869834 -0.52157721  0.09026303  1.000000000 -0.267341912  0.17065244 -0.958919185
34: 2011-05-02  x3 -0.07579900  0.12441121  0.43261423 -0.267341912  1.000000000  0.76093821  0.328896757
35: 2011-06-02  x2  0.14630187 -0.02121530  0.23351755  1.000000000  0.214190295 -0.44671768  0.593123871
36: 2011-06-02  x3  0.92090833 -0.22766946 -0.53092628  0.214190295  1.000000000 -0.01796403 -0.439337427
37: 2011-07-02  x2  0.24085187 -0.01442061  0.46151828  1.000000000 -0.634303063  0.60757379  0.581212136
38: 2011-07-02  x3 -0.65826708 -0.52006935 -0.17321499 -0.634303063  1.000000000 -0.38542234 -0.856055763
39: 2011-08-02  x2  0.13923866 -0.01168973  0.40294949  1.000000000  0.163579759  0.05517129 -0.006048453
40: 2011-08-02  x3  0.11823951  0.80057447 -0.26414984  0.163579759  1.000000000  0.71011089 -0.061702941
          Time var          Id        norm           y           x2           x3          x4           x5
```

Comment: Very nice! Thank you very much!